# Размерность RGB и RGBA изображения после свертки

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

К примеру, есть изображение `500х500х3` (или х4, если `RGBA`) и ядро для свертки `3х3х3`.

Почему после свертки выходное изображение уже имеет большую размерность каналов (`500х500х9`)?
Каким образом это происходит и какие значения туда записываются на выходе?

Comment: Добрый день, хотел бы Вам посоветовать ресурс Data Science, на нём по этой тематике достаточно много ответов, а на этом сайте вопрос может быть не понят сообществом или закрыт.

Comment: Сколько фильтров вы используете? Если хотите получить адекватный ответ то приведите в вопросе соответствующий код

Answer (score 2):

Одним из параметров сверточного слоя является число фильтров, которое и задает глубину выходного (следующего) слоя на данном сверточном слое. `Глубина слоя` в общем случае - это **не** число цветовых каналов, это скорее можно рассматривать как набор обнаруженных признаков (например вертикальные линии, горизонтальные, дианональные, под определенным углом X, Y, Z, дуги, окружности, эллипсы и т.д.). Чем больше у нас сверточных слоев и фильтров в них тем более сложные признаки ИНС учиться распознавать (например человеческий глаз или клюв птицы или контур мотоцикла или машины). Каждый фильтр в вашем случае имеет размерность `3x3x3` и судя по размерности `500x500x9` - в данном сверточном слое было 9 фильтров.

Если к цветному изображению размерности `500х500х3` применить *один* фильтр с ядром свертки `3х3х3` и `padding='same'` в сверточном слое то на выходе у нас получится 2D матрица/тензор размерности `500x500x1`. Последнее число размерности соответствует числу фильтров.